# C#: Optimizing error prevention with the input console

Tags: c#, console-application, do-while

I've just started learning C# using Rob Miles' C# Programming Yellow Book and some related lab exercises from his website. I did one of them and produced a solution that works...(there's not one provided). I wanted it to not crash if the user inputs nonsensical answers or a string that can't be converted into an integer(I Googled this and found the TryParse method. The textbook briefly taught the try/catch method, but that didn't seem useful for a user interface, i.e. to let the program continue after a bad input). I also set it up so that, in one of these cases, it sends out an alternate message. I've ended up with a somewhat long code... a do/while within a do/while and a do/while within a while. If you have any tips for streamlining this, I'd be much obliged.

Best,
Elliot

```
using System;
using System.IO;

static class Cinema
{
    static void Main()
    {
    int[] selection = new int[] //array for the age requirements of each film
        {
        15, 15, 12, 18, 0
        };
    string filmNumberText; //console input for the film number 
    int filmNumber; //input string parsed as integer 
    string ageText; //console input for age
    int age; //parsed age string
    int ageLimit; //age requirement for selected film

    Console.Write("Welcome to our Multiplex.\n\n");
    Console.WriteLine(@"We are presently showing:
    1. Rush (15) 
    2. How I Live Now (15)
    3. Thor: The Dark World (12A)
    4. Filth (18)
    5. Planes (U)");
    do  //loops as long as input is not between 1 and 5
    {
        do //loops as long as the input is not an integer
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter the number of the film you wish to see: ");
            filmNumberText = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (int.TryParse(filmNumberText, out filmNumber) == false);
    } while (filmNumber < 1 || filmNumber > 5);

    filmNumber = filmNumber - 1; //changes input from 1-5 to 0-4
    ageLimit = selection[filmNumber]; //selects age requirement from array

     //loops as long as input is not an integer

        do
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter your age: ");
        ageText = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (int.TryParse(ageText, out age) == false); // repeats if input is not an integer



    while (age < 0 || age > 125) //if integer is is too small or too large...
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write("\nInvalid age. Please enter an age between 0 and 125: ");
            ageText = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (int.TryParse(ageText, out age) == false); //check again if input is an integer
    }
    if (age < ageLimit) //if too young for the given film
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAccess denied - you are too young");
        }
    else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease call our office at 888-999-2928 to reserve tickets.");
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: Working code that you want critiqued belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but one thing I would add is a message if the input is invalid.  You could also break the code into methods to make it cleaner if you want.

Comment: This is actually pretty good. The improvement that I would make, since there is a lot of repetitive code, would be to move some of it to a separate method which can be reused. This is what @user3598756 has done in his answer. That way code gets shorter and you have less places where you can make a mistake (bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to remove some do while loop from your code. is this what are you looking for?

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] selection = new int[] //array for the age requirements of each film
    {
    15, 15, 12, 18, 0
    };
    string filmNumberText; //console input for the film number 
    int filmNumber; //input string parsed as integer 
    string ageText; //console input for age
    int age; //parsed age string
    int ageLimit; //age requirement for selected film

    Console.Write("Welcome to our Multiplex.\n\n");
    Console.WriteLine(@"We are presently showing:
1. Rush (15) 
2. How I Live Now (15)
3. Thor: The Dark World (12A)
4. Filth (18)
5. Planes (U)");
    do  //loops as long as input is not between 1 and 5
    {

        Console.Write("\nEnter the number of the film you wish to see: ");
        filmNumberText = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (int.TryParse(filmNumberText, out filmNumber) == false || (filmNumber < 1 || filmNumber > 5));

    filmNumber = filmNumber - 1; //changes input from 1-5 to 0-4
    ageLimit = selection[filmNumber]; //selects age requirement from array

    //loops as long as input is not an integer

    do
    {
        Console.Write("\nPlease enter an age between 0 and 125:");
        ageText = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (int.TryParse(ageText, out age) == false || (age < 0 || age > 125)); //check again if input is an integer

    if (age < ageLimit) //if too young for the given film
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nAccess denied - you are too young");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease call our office at 888-999-2928 to reserve tickets.");
    }

    Console.Read();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That certainly is more efficient if we eliminate any alternate messages addressing specific errors.

Comment: Yes, I tried my best to understand and write program which is similar to your logic. Please accept if it has really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider the following refactoring:

```
  static class Cinema
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] titles = new string[] {"Rush", "How I Live Now", "Thor: The Dark World", "Filth", "Planes" };//array for the age requirements of each film
            int[] selection = new int[] { 15, 15, 12, 18, 0 };//array for the age requirements of each film
            int filmNumber; //parsed film number string 
            int age; //parsed age string

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to our Multiplex.\n\nWe are presently showing:");
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} ({2})",i+1, titles[i],selection[i]);
            }


            filmNumber = GetIntNumber(1, 5, "\nEnter the number of the film you wish to see: ", "\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 5: ");

            //loops as long as input is not an integer

            age = GetIntNumber(0, 125, "\nEnter your age: ", "\nPlease enter an age between 0 and 125: ") - 1; 
            if (age < selection[filmNumber-1]) //if too young for the given film
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nAccess denied - you are too young");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nPlease call our office at 888-999-2928 to reserve tickets.");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static int GetIntNumber(int min, int max, string prompt, string inputPrompt)
        {
            int number;

            Console.Write(prompt);
            do  //loops as long as input is not between 1 and 5
            {
                Console.Write(inputPrompt);
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) //loops as long as the input is not an integer
                {
                    Console.Write("\nYou must enter an integer number!");
                } 
            } while (number < min || number >max);
            return number;
        }
```

edit to throw in **Alternative 1** for `GetInNumber()` method prompts handling:

```
    static int GetInNumber(int min, int max, string prompt, string inputPrompt)
    {
        int number;

        Console.Write(prompt);
        do  //loops as long as input is not between 1 and 5
        {
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) //loops as long as the input is not an integer
            {
                Console.Write("\nYou must enter an integer number!: ");
            }
            if (number < min || number > max) Console.Write(inputPrompt); //<--| write input prompt if number out of range
        } while (number < min || number > max);

        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Hey, that's great thank you. It seems like too much to print both the prompt and inputPrompt the first time the user is prompted. I've been trying to figure out a way to only use the prompt the first time, the inputPrompt when the input value is out of range, and "You must enter an integer number!" when the input value is not an integer, but I'm having trouble. Any ideas?

Comment: You are welcome. Well, I chose the initial "double" prompt not to cheat the user and giving it sufficient clues as to how to properly input an answer. anyhow if you really need to avoid initial double prompt see _alternative 1_ in edited answer, which however lowers the solution "elegance". Finally you may want to mark my answer as accepted, thank you!

Comment: Yes, as I'm trying to learn, I just wanted to know how it could be done. Thanks again for your help!